# Pivot - how to write the code if there are Null in row

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data is below

```
id  DENM                                     DD
1   Point 5-Point 4;  (Sill22);              902
1   Point 3-Point 5;  (Right Jammy);         2014
1   Point 3-Point 5;  (Right Jammy);         2004
1   Point 2-Point 3;  (Head11);              902
1   Point 2-Point 3;  (Head11);              842
1   Point 4-Point 2;  (Left Jammy);          2014
1   Point 4-Point 2;  (Left Jammy);          2004
2   Point 4-Point 2;  (Left Jammy);          885
2   Point 4-Point 2;  (Left Jammy);          800
```

I am joining above table to a different table by ID.
But before joining the data to the data I want the data to be like below

```
1    902    2014    2004    902     842     2014    2004
2    885    800     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

How to write the query in SQL

Comment: What have you tried?  Any method of pivoting that I can think of will produce that result.

Comment: Actually @GordonLinoff, no method will guarantee to produce that result. There's no way to define the order of the rows.

Comment: @LuisCazares, what does order of rows have to do with pivoting? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Andrew The order of the rows will define the order of the columns once the data is pivoted. Although, it might not matter as the values for id 2 should go on the last columns if some logic is in place (same DENM).

Comment: The order of the columns is defined up-front in the code that performs the pivot. If you want a so-called "dynamic pivot", there are approaches that can achieve this (and could presumably be modified to sort the columns based on a row_number) but that's quite a bit of extra coding.

Answer (score 1):

pivots in T-SQL are all the same;

- find the column's values you want to columnize
- find the the column to which you assign a transformation (sum, max, min, etc.)
- the rest is gravy

In your case you have a table

```
select
 id,
 DENM,
 DD
from [table_name]
```

you want to join this to your other table:

```
select
 id,
 DENM,
 DD,
 t2.[fields]
from [table_name] t1 with (nolock)
join [second_table] t2 with (nolock)
 on t1.id = t2.id
```

and put a pivot on it:

```
select
 id,
 [field list]
from
(
 select
  id,
  DENM,
  DD,
  t2.[fields]
 from [table_name] t1 with (nolock)
 join [second_table] t2 with (nolock)
  on t1.id = t2.id
) data
pivot
(
 sum(value field)
 for [DD] in (@collist)
) as pvtData
```

I recommend building your [field list] out of a previous query that build a nice clean stuffed list of values. Something like this:

```
    DECLARE @collist nvarchar(max);
    SELECT @collist = STUFF(
    (
        SELECT 
            distinct ',' + quotename(Variable)  
        from
            [table_name] t1
        group by 
            Variable
                    FOR XML PATH(''), root('MyString'), type).value('/MyString[1]','varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
```

This will require that you use dynamic SQL and finish off your stored proc with

```
exec sp_executesql @queryText
```

Comment: What error are you getting? or is it the result you are not satisfied with?